# Void pointer without type casting

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, casting

```
int main
{
void* i;
printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

Output : (garbage value)
How does a void pointer determines a data type without typecasting??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilers usually do not bother what are types of arguments passed to function `printf`.

The function is declared the following way

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

As you see there is only the first parameter has explicitly specified type. In general case compilers unable to check whether the other arguments are valid.

When the function is executed it parses its first parameter searching format specifies and according these format specifiers tries to interpretate the following arguments.

In your example the format string has format specifier `%d`

```
printf("%d",i);
```

So the function interpretates the value of i as of type `int`. Take into account that (C Standard)

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the **behavior is undefined**.

Among other things you even did not initialize variable `i`.

Answer (score 6):

> How does a void pointer determines a data type without typecasting??

The uninitialized pointer value is cast to an `int` and the `int` is printed.

Strictly speaking, your program is subject to undefined behavior on account of two issues:

1. You are using an uninitialized variable.
2. You are using a pointer where an `int` is expected in `printf`.

Comment: Yeah , specifier may not but accessing it may cause it .

Comment: I don't think there is UB. Just a garbage value will be printed. When dereferencing `i`, there wil be UB.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I don't agree wrt no UB.  The `sizeof(int)` may not be the same as `sizeof(void*)` and if it isn't the same size, possibly corrupt the `varargs` implementation.  Also, `printf` does no casting AFAIK.  It totally trusts the programmer to send the correct type, based on the format specifier.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, You are right: 6.3.2.3 "_Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type [and vice versa]. Except ... the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined._"

Answer (score 1):

Garbage is printed in the example because `i` is a pointer and `printf` will just print its content; namely, the address `i` is holding. If you wanna print the integer that `i` is pointing to, then use `printf("%d", *i)`, but this will fail since you cannot dereference a void pointer. It won't compile. Casting before dereferencing is necessary.

Regarding how a void pointer determines the value type: it doesn't. It just points to it. You must tell it what the data type is being pointed to if you want to use the value somewhere else.

```c
int main(){
  int i = 10;
  void *ptr = &i;

  /* Cast to a int pointer and then dereference. */
  printf("%d", *((int*)ptr));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: but in my program if i do printf("%d", (int*)i);   it gives me same value which i got in my program(the one in the question)

Comment: Do you understand the concept of pointers? `(int*)i` just tells the compiler "treat variable `i` as a pointer to an `int`". If you wanna access the thing that `i` is pointing to you have to dereference it, so you have to make a type cast (since it is a void pointer) and then dereference `*(int*)i`.

Answer (score 0):

When printing pointers, use the [`%p`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbafc2a9cb3ef699) format.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d",i);
```

Takes whatever `i` is, casts it to an `int`, and prints that.

Which is garbage since you didn't initialize your `i` properly.